# React Native Android Development - Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' on Windows Webstorm

Tags: android, react-native, webstorm

I have an issue with installing and running the React-Native Android guide to create [AwesomeProject](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup). I am using a Windows 10 environment with Webstorm as my IDE. When ever I run the following command, the emulator fails to launch:

```
react-native run-android
```

Here is a screen cap of the Web Storm:
[image]

I have all the SDK and JDK configured in my System Environments, this is why I don't the error. Here are the additional steps I took configuring Gradle plugin:
[image]

I have googled the issue but the solutions I found were for MacOS users and didn't translate for Windows.

Has anyone come across this issue on Windows and fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by installing **[JDK 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/)** as listed in the React Native guide. Then updated both the Environment Variables and the `gradle.properties` file.

**I ONLY GOT IT TO WORK IN ANDROID STUDIO**

[image: Environment Variables]

[image: gradle.properties file]

This seems to have worked for me.
But now I got a new error to fix, which basically is that application isn't detecting a device or emulation.

[image: Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug']

However, to get around that, I have to ensure that I open the AVD Manager and run one of the configured virtual devices prior to executing the command `npx react-native run-android`.

This does annoy me having to perform that task first. If anyone knows how to get it to automatically run a default virtual device, that would be nice.

[image: Successful execution of Awesome Project]